# How to I dynamically resize an array in VBA? I keep getting subscript and index issues

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim codesArray() As Variant
  ...
If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
  ...
Else
     ReDim Preserve codesArray(UBound(codesArray) + 1) ' Error subscript 
     codesArray(UBound(codesArray)) = cell.Value
End If
```

I am not sure why I am getting an index out of range error.

Basically everytime the worksheet name is not found, I want to add it to the Array and then eventually let the user know the names of the worksheets that are missing.

So the best employee would have 0 missing worksheets. The worst would be missing them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said `var()` will error out at bound checking.
To do this without any errors you can use a code like this:

```
Dim codesArray
  ...
If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
  ...
Else
  If IsArray(codesArray) Then
    ReDim Preserve codesArray(UBound(codesArray) + 1)
  Else
    ReDim codesArray(0)
  End If
  codesArray(UBound(codesArray)) = cell.Value
End If
```

or like this:

```
Dim codesArray
  ...
If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
  ...
Else
  If IsArray(codesArray) Then
    ReDim Preserve codesArray(UBound(codesArray) + 1)
    codesArray(UBound(codesArray)) = cell.Value
  Else
    codesArray = Array(cell.Value)
  End If
End If
```

The good thing about this is the avoidance of any error-changing-code. So if there is a different reason for an error, it won't be suppressed. 
Also it should be self-explaining.... if you still have any questions left, just ask ;)

Comment: I used the second one and I'm still getting the same error. Subscript out of range. I think you're right about the array being uninitialized.

Comment: @softwareisfun have you changed your `Dim codesArray() As Variant` to `Dim codesArray` ???

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with `UBound(codesArray)`. You can't call `UBound()` on an array which hasn't yet been dimensioned.

You can use error handling to cover this case. Abstracted to a potentially useful sub:

```
Sub ExtendArray(A As Variant, Optional NewPlaces = 1, Optional LBase = 0)
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A) To UBound(A) + NewPlaces)
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    ReDim A(LBase To LBase + NewPlaces - 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variable k .

```
Dim codesArray() As Variant
Dim k As Long
  ...
If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
  ...
Else
     ReDim Preserve codesArray(k) ' Error subscript
     codesArray(k) = Cell.Value
     k = k + 1
End If
```

Upper code Array number begin at 0.

Bellow code Array number begin at 1.  Lbound(codeArray) is 1.

```
Dim codesArray() As Variant
Dim k As Long
  ...
If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
  ...
Else
    k = k + 1
     ReDim Preserve codesArray(1 To k) ' Error subscript
     codesArray(k) = Cell.Value

End If
```

Comment: @softwareisfun, when  we first enter the loop, k is 0.  the array size start from 1, but array number is 0.   codeArray(0), codeArray(1), codeArray(2),... ,codeArray(n)

Comment: @softwareisfun,  upper code  Lbound(codeArray)  is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use a collection rather than an array - no need to resize then.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim vSheetNames As Variant
    Dim sht As Variant
    Dim colMissing As Collection
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim sMissingString As String
    Dim lLastComma As Long

    vSheetNames = Array("Sheet1") ', "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"

    'Build a collection of missing sheets.
    Set colMissing = New Collection
    For Each sht In vSheetNames
        If Not WorkSheetExists(CStr(sht)) Then
            colMissing.Add sht
        End If
    Next sht

    If colMissing.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All sheets are present", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        'Build the message string.
        For Each vItem In colMissing
            sMissingString = sMissingString & vItem & ", "
        Next vItem

        'Remove the last comma.
        sMissingString = Left(sMissingString, Len(sMissingString) - 2)

        'Replace last comma with the word 'and'.
        lLastComma = InStrRev(sMissingString, ",")
        If lLastComma > 0 Then
            sMissingString = Left(sMissingString, lLastComma - 1) & " and" & Mid(sMissingString, lLastComma + 1)
        End If

        MsgBox IIf(colMissing.Count = 1, "This sheet is ", "These sheets are ") & "missing: " & vbCr & _
            sMissingString, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

    End If

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```